# Is "rid you of" a valid phrase?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality

Writing about a product, is the following sentence valid?

> X aims to rid you of Y

I remember seeing the phrase "rid you of" somewhere before, but this doesn't seem valid for some reason. Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as in "a robber would rid you of your money."

Comment: I think *rid* is more often applied to *unwanted* things. Such as insecticidal shampoo to *rid your dog of fleas*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, in my case, I am using it for a similar case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you're right.  It is usually used ironically in cases like this. E.g. Robin Hood said to the duke "That money purse looks awfully heavy, let me rid you of it."

Comment: @Kevin, Shrikant Sharat: Given this *unwanted* implication, it's odd that kiamlaluno's Answer currently has less votes. Although Kevin's Answer isn't exactly *wrong*, I feel compelled to say kiamlaluno's is *better*. Presumably the lower rating is simply because votes had already been cast before it was posted. Maybe people should be encouraged to go back over old Questions and upvote *later, but better* Answers where it's clear the ratings don't reflect a true concensus. Anyway, no disrespect, Kevin, but I shall attempt to do that myself on this one now (if my rep allows!)

Comment: Hah! I have now successfully reversed the ratings!

Answer (score 9):

*Rid* means "make someone or something free of a troublesome or unwanted person or thing."

> This shampoo will rid you of your dandruff.

Comment: Agreed - Have a look here --- https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rid+you+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crid%20you%20of%3B%2Cc0